# Is there any package management in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

We've reccently started working with IOS. I wonder if there are any packagement like rubgems (ruby) or npm (nodejs) for Objective-C?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Seems that it haven't any package manager.

Comment: many IDEs don't come with package management built in. However, there is, at the very least, third party package management for most popular languages today. CocoaPods is objective-c's popular ("standard") third party package manager. We're looking for productive answers. Software engineering is a world supported by the community, so if there's a demand, there will always be multiple supplies

Answer (score 15):

[CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki) is a recent Objective-C library package manager. From [its RubyGems.org page](http://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods):

> CocoaPods is an Objective-C library package manager. It tries to take away all hard work of maintaining your dependencies, but in a lean and flexible way. Its goal is to create a more centralized overview of open-source libraries and unify the way in which we deal with them. CocoaPods will calculate the right set of versions of all of your project's dependencies, install them, and set them up to be build as part of a dependency static library, which your project links against.

Comment: It's very young and IIRC only supports iOS projects at the moment (though OS X support is on the radar). I'd say only use CocoaPods if you're an early adopter type.

Comment: @Chuck Yup, that’s a sensible advice. On the other hand, the more people using and working on it, the faster it can improve.

Comment: @Chuck It now supports OS X as well. It’s indeed sensible advice, but, like Bavarious says, more usage/testing is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ruby, But I believe you are referring to what objective-c calls Frameworks.  These are basically libraries that your code can link into. They are added in the Xcode project settings and then under Build Phases and then "Link Binary With Libraries"

These Frameworks hold the code for like core location, core data, graphics and other very handy libraries.

Comment: Frameworks aren't managed centrally with dependencies automatically followed at install time. Well, macports or homebrew can manage them, but it's not official as part of the compiler like gems/cpan/pythoneggs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C sources aren't typically hosted here, but you may be interested in [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). Its packages are along the lines of those found in common 'nix package managers, so it will be useful if you want more traditional C or C++ libraries, which you can happily integrate with Objective-C projects.